# How to insert unique ID into Firebase item on initial push()?

Tags: firebase

When using `push()` with Firebase, Firebase generates a unique ID, such as `-JZl_BbXymAnOCPppMzN`. I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to get that ID into the item I'm pushing during that first `push()`. For example, say I'm pushing an item as such:

```
var uid = "notset";
uid = fb.push({Name: name, Status: status, Position: position, UID: uid});
```

In this example, `uid.name()` holds my unique ID. So my first thought was to then update the item with the unique ID I now know, like:

```
var uidname = uid.name();
fb.child(uid.name()).update({UID: uidname});
```

And this does work.

However, I'm also relying on an `on()` to detect children added so I can deal with them as they arrive. For example:

```
fb.on('child_added',function(dataSnapshot) {
      var newstatus = dataSnapshot.val();
      var status = newstatus.Status;
      var name = newstatus.Name;
      var position = newstatus.Position;
      var uid = newstatus.UID;
      console.log
        ("Name: "+name+", Status: "+status+", Position: "+position+", UID: "+uid);
});
```

But because of the async nature of Firebase, this `on()` runs after the `push()` but before the `update()`. So my `console.log()` prints out a uid of `notset` instead of the correct UID.

Is there a different strategy I should be following? I suppose I can generate my own UIDs and push them to Firebase using `firebaseRef.child('myUID').set()`, but it seems there must be an easier way?

Comment: `push` is a client-side operation in Firebase, so nothing is sent to the server yet. Can't you split it into: `var ref = fb.push(); /* use ref.name() here*/ ref.set({Name: name, Status: status, Position: position, UID: uid});`?

Comment: this is a nice elegant solution; write up as answer and i'll select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase's `push` is a client-side operation, so nothing is sent to the server yet.

Instead of calling `push` **with** the data in one go, you can you split it into two separate calls:

```
var ref = fb.push(); 
/* use ref.name() here*/ 
ref.set({Name: name, Status: status, Position: position, UID: uid});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of this will work, but try this:

1. In fb.push, do not set the UID at all, leave it blank and firebase will generate it.
2. In fb.on, instead of newstatus.UID use dataSnapshot.name()